# Limit number of rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheets document that keeps adding hundreds of rows and slowing down the project, and sometimes causing it to crash.

Is there a way to limit the number of rows to say 100.  I do not want to remove all empty rows, because it is a log that constantly needs data added to so a new row is always needed.  However, we only use around 100 rows for each document.

I am not sure if this is due to a script I have attached or if it is just part of google sheets.

```
   function setFormat() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
for (var i in sheets) {
    var MaxRows = sheets[i].getMaxRows();
    var MaxColumns = sheets[i].getMaxColumns();

sheets[i].getRange(2, 1, MaxRows, MaxColumns)
.setFontFamily('Arial')
.setFontSize('9')
.setFontStyle('normal')
.setFontColor('black')
.setVerticalAlignment('center')
.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);

sheets[i].getRange(1, 1, 1, MaxColumns)
.setFontFamily('Comfortaa')
.setFontSize('9')
.setFontStyle('bold')
.setFontColor('black')
.setVerticalAlignment('center')
.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);

sheets[i].autoResizeColumns(1, 1);
sheets[i].setColumnWidths(2, 1, 80);
sheets[i].setColumnWidths(3, 1, 75);
sheets[i].setColumnWidths(4, 1, 90);
sheets[i].setColumnWidths(5, 4, 45);
sheets[i].setColumnWidths(9, 3, 75);
sheets[i].setColumnWidths(12, 2, 130);
sheets[i].setColumnWidths(14, 1, 95);
sheets[i].setColumnWidths(15, 1, 100);
sheets[i].setColumnWidths(16, 1, 95);
sheets[i].setRowHeights(2, MaxRows-1, 15);
sheets[i].setRowHeights(1, 1, 16);   }}
```

and

```
   function dataAlignment1() {

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var lr = s.getLastRow();
     var r = s.getRange(2, 1, lr, 2);
     var set = r.setHorizontalAlignment('left');
   }

   function dataAlignment2() {

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var lr = s.getLastRow();
     var r = s.getRange(2, 3, lr, 1);
     var set = r.setHorizontalAlignment('right');
   }

   function dataAlignment3() {

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var lr = s.getLastRow();
     var r = s.getRange(2, 4, lr, 1);
     var set = r.setHorizontalAlignment('left');
   }

   function dataAlignment4() {

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var lr = s.getLastRow();
     var r = s.getRange(2, 5, lr, 4);
     var set = r.setHorizontalAlignment('left');
   }

   function dataAlignment5() {

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var lr = s.getLastRow();
     var r = s.getRange(2, 9, lr, 2);
     var set = r.setHorizontalAlignment('right');
   }

   function dataAlignment6() {

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var lr = s.getLastRow();
     var r = s.getRange(2, 11, lr, 1);
    var set = r.setHorizontalAlignment('center');
   }

   function dataAlignment7() {

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var lr = s.getLastRow();
     var r = s.getRange(2, 12, lr, 4);
     var set = r.setHorizontalAlignment('left');
   }

   function dataAlignment8() {

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var lr = s.getLastRow();
     var r = s.getRange(2, 16, lr, 1);
     var set = r.setHorizontalAlignment('center');
   }

   function headerAlignment() {

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var lr = s.getLastRow();
     var lc = s.getLastColumn();
     var r = s.getRange(1, 1, 1, lc);
     var set = r.setHorizontalAlignment('center');
   }
```

Comment: `Is there a way to limit the number of rows to say 100` No. Are you saying you want to delete every row beyond 100?

Comment: Your question is very unclear and quite vague.

Comment: No, what I am saying is each morning I come back and there will be around 1000 rows.  Everything over 100 is empty, I didn't add them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can control the number of rows inserted from the script. You can remove or append to the sheet. As much as I understood, I think you can save each 100 rows in a file or append the latest 100 row on the top of the file or remove the oldest row/save it in a different  sheet and add the new row.

Comment: As far as I know the script is not adding any rows, unless it is unintentional.

Comment: I think you can append scripts. Please check this link : https://m.wikihow.com/Run-a-Script-on-Google-Sheets

Comment: I added the script I am using.